# Django - Inherit Permissions in Mixins

Tags: python, django

I have two models. I want to inherit permissions from one model to another.
So here's my pseud-django-code:

```
class BaseMixin:
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = (
            ("can_change_something", "Can change something"),
        )


class Article(BaseMixin):
    # some fields
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_change_something_on_articles", "Can change something on articles...")
        )
```

My problem: When I go to the admin panel to groups these permissions don't show up. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to inherit the `Meta`, change `class Meta:` to `class Meta(BaseMixin.Meta):`

Note: this only works if the model class you are inheriting from is `abstract = True`

instead of using `permissions` on your abstract model use `default_permissions` - make sure to add the initial default permission: `'add', 'change', 'delete', 'view'`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#default-permissions`

Comment: I tried it. It worked but I cant set any new permissions on `Article` now.

Comment: `default_permissions` is the way to do it - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#default-permissions

Comment: any chance you can accept the answer if it is correct?

Comment: Yes I thought there would be another way, so I first tried it with properties but that didn't work either and then I forgot to accept your answer. Sorry.